# Aligning radio buttons in multiple rows in android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I am new to android development and I was wondering how to do the following.

I want to put 6 radio buttons on a screen in multiple rows. Based on the screen size I want to put 3 radio buttons in the first row so that they occupy the first row and then the other three in the second row and so on.

Can some one please tell me how to write the xml for this so that it is generalised to every phone that is used.

Comment: You could create the layout XML file then include it in other activity layouts as you require it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup 
        android:id="@+id/firstone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="first"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="second"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="third"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/secondone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="first"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninja"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="second"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_tes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="third"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, one of the ways to achieve what you are looking for is to use Relative Layout. You can position one group over the other. You can define the orientation of the RadioGroups too as Vertical or Horizontal. More on radio Buttons at, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView with android:numColumns="auto_fit"

Comment: could you please show me how the xml file looks like?

Comment: Just place GridView in xml file with numColumns="auto_fit" and set adapter to the GridView